# How to start modeling a van (the inside frame)?

Tags: modeling, objects, workflow, photorealism

I'm new to Blender, and have a specific request... Something I'm struggling with in Blender. I'm first, sorry for my grammar, english is not my native language ! I hope you'll understand everything !

Well, I'm into my own van renovation, and right now in the conception part, and the first step is taking the proper mesures and make the van as a full object in 3D and more precisely the inside part. I obviously need blender for that, I've tried in Sketchup, but is not as good as I would like it ! 
And unfortunately, my ability in Blender are not going far... And I don't know just... How to start ?
Its even harder as the van is not straight at all (curved lines are everywhere !!), so I can't start by a simple cube...

I just join to this post some pictures of the van itself, as it can show what I'm struggling with : the framing of the van...
That's how its look like inside. As you can see, there's a outside cover which is the van body, make of big metal sheets, so its regular and smooth. And glue to it the inside frame, made of several little parts, with several kind of straight/curved geometric shapes...

So, I'm coming to you today, as I really need a methodological line to start modeling the van ! Maybe, if you know any videos tutorial that explain a similar method than the one I should use, or... anything that will do ! :)

Thanks in advance,
Cheers !!

Estelle

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

[image: image 4]

Comment: I would recommend doing a video search for `Blender Hard Surface Modelling Tutorial`. This being said, you may have to watch quite a few videos for things to seem helpful to you as a beginner, but it is good to see what people are doing at the very least. The other option on the free side that I would recommend is getting signed up on [BlenderArtist](blenderartists.org), as they have sections on tutorials and a user help. The other option is using a site like [cgcookie](https://cgcookie.com/learn-blender), where you pay for quality instruction (worth it if you want to take the easier road).

Comment: For the white plates part I'd go a two mesh system, one for the outer shell another for the inner structure. Keep the inner structure a "paper thin" mesh with a *Subdivision* modifier, add control loops to adjust curvature radius, then add thickness with a *Solidify* modifier